# Python - extract float (billions) numbers from string

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

So my question is how can I extract a number expressed in Billions who are actually a string.
e.g: $5,518.51 B

And actually that's work, but only for number lik 249.23 not for the number like 5,512.50 I want what is before the ',' also.

I have tried like this:

business['sales']=business['sales'].astype('str').str.extractall('(\d+.\d+)').unstack().fillna('').sum(axis=1).astype(float)

Comment: The data cleaning step you want is to `.replace(",", "")` so those troublesome `,` commas are out of the picture.

Comment: Two questions: will there be other units in the mix (M, K, etc.)? Do you want 5518.51 or 5518510000000 as the output?

Comment: @CodeDifferent I want 5518.51 as output.